# Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer

Tags: delphi, ssl

i use delphi xe6, windows10, openssl 1.0.2u win32, when i connect to many www i don't have a problem, but when i try to connect at https://www.scuderiequirinale.it/ ,I have all time the error "Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer." i tried to change the SSLOptions.SSLVersions with many combinations... but i have anytime the error... i search in similar error but i don't find the solution... do you have an idea?

Thankyou!!

this is the code:

```
  hIOHand.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2,sslvSSLv23];
  hIOHand.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1]; //i will try with all combinations
  Web.IOHandler := hIOHand;

  Web.OnHeadersAvailable := CheckResponseCharset;
  Web.Request.UserAgent := INET_USERAGENT;       //Custom user agent string
  Web.RedirectMaximum := INET_REDIRECT_MAX;      //Maximum redirects
  Web.HandleRedirects := INET_REDIRECT_MAX <> 0; //Handle redirects
  Web.ReadTimeOut := INET_TIMEOUT_SECS * 1000;   //Read timeout msec
  Web.ConnectTimeout := INET_TIMEOUT_SECS div 2 * 1000;

  try
    Sito := Web.Get(FUrl);
    Sito := DateToStr(Web.Response.LastModified) + Sito;
  except
    on e : exception do
      Sito := '!!|!!|ERR-: ' +FUrl+#32+e.Message;
 end
finally
  EndTime := Now;
  TStr.Free;
  Web.Free;
  hIOHand.Free;
end;
```

Comment: the second " hIOHand.SSLOptions.SSLVersions" is only used for test

Comment: Error 10054 means that the server closed the connection. Why? Because the server detected something not OK according to their rules. This could be an SSL version as you tried, but also a cipher or even your own IP address (In that case it should not work from a browser either). You should also try to use the latest OpenSSL libraries (No idea how to do that with Indy: I use ICS).

Comment: Tx... I verified and the OpenSSL libraries is the latest version. When i try to access to the web site with the browser i have a normal response. But with my program i have this problem.

Comment: @ondertol "*I verified and the OpenSSL libraries is the latest version*" - can you be more specific? Which EXACT version did you actually try?  Indy does not yet "officially" support OpenSSL 1.1.x, only 1.0.2 and earlier. And `u` is the last in the 1.0.2 series. There is ["experimental" support](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) for OpenSSL 1.1.x that hasn't been mainlined yet.

Comment: @ondertol "*When i try to access to the web site with the browser i have a normal response. But with my program i have this problem*" - then I suggest you use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to see if the problem happens during the TLS handshake or not. If it is, check for any differences between the browser's handshake and your app's handshake. If the problem is after the handshake, then compare the actual HTTP requests for differences. To capture the raw HTTP data, you can enable your browser's built-in debugger, and attach a `TIdLog...` component to `TIdHTTP.Intercept`

Comment: @ondertol BTW, which version of Indy are you using? If you are using the version that was bundled with XE6, you need to upgrade to the [latest version of Indy from GitHub](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/).  For instance, it is possible that the server in question requires SNI when using TLS 1.2 (many modern servers do), but Indy bundled with XE6 did not support SNI yet, that was [added 2 years later](https://www.indyproject.org/2016/01/10/client-side-sni-support-added-to-tidssliohandlersocketopenssl/).

Comment: @Remy... i had update che indy library (at last version), but the probem is the same. The version of the OpenSSL lbraries are 1.0.2u... i think the only possibility is to use Wireshark (i don't know it, but will try soon). Tx a lot

Comment: @Remy now i had used Wireshark: the difference are in "Client Hello". With browser the Chiper Suites are 16 (vs 86 with Delphi) and the Extension Lenght are 403 with browser (vs 85 with Delphi)... for example the browser have Extension Reserved (GREASE), key_share, psk_key_excange_mode, padding, etc...  not present in Delphi.

Comment: @ondertol is the SNI extension present in Indy's "client hello" and set to `www.scuderiequirinale.it`?

Comment: @Remy: i don't find any SNI or Server Name Indication Extension (not with Indy but i think is on browser's extension named "server name"). In indy's exstensions i have only: ec_point_formats, supported_groups, session_ticket, signature_algorithms and heartbeat.

Comment: @ondertol "*i don't find any SNI or Server Name Indication Extension*" - Then that is likely the issue.  If you truly are using an up-to-date Indy (what does the `TIdHTTP.Version` property report?) and a fairly up-to-date OpenSSL (what does the `IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion()` function report?), then the SNI extension *should* always be present if you have TLS 1.2 (`sslvTLSv1_2`) enabled.

Comment: @Remy: the TIdHTTP.Version is '10.6.0.5122', the IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion is  'OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019'. and  SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2,sslvSSLv23];

Comment: @ondertol "*the TIdHTTP.Version is '10.6.0.5122'*" - that is NOT even close to the latest version of Indy. The current version is 10.6.2, so you are a LONG ways off from the latest. You are likely still using the version that shipped with XE6 (Indy bumped to 10.6.1 around XE7). So, makes sense then why SNI is missing. On a side note, don't use `sslvSSLv23` in the `SSLVersions` property. In this example, it will just get ignored.

Comment: @Remy  :O   i tried to install before the today's messages the last version downloaded from  GitHub, but now i know that i have a problem... i tried another time now the installazion but the version not change.... i use the Fullc_XE6.bat and i have only warging not error... i must study the problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221971/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-ondertol).